# c++ get double array from Matlab engine

Tags: c++, matlab-engine

I have `C++` code which calls `MATLAB` function using MATLAB engine.

The `MATLAB` function result is an array of 3 doubles.

How can I get that array back to `C++` as a double array ?

Comment: double yourArray[3] = fMatlabFunction(); Can you directly call the matlab function (wrapped or otherwise) in C++ already?

Comment: I call the matlab function using engEvalString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
// e.g. array_name=[1 2 3] in MATLAB
Engine * matlab;
...
mxArray * m = engGetVariable(matlab, "array_name");
double * ptr = (double *) mxGetData(m); // ptr is the double array you need

// you can skip the following if you don't use OpenCV 
Mat mat(3, 1, CV_64F); // CV_64F <=> double
memcpy(mat.ptr(), ptr, 3*sizeof(double));
```